# Create a street line feature with right-of-way widths using a street centreline file and property boundary polygon layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I would like to create a street line feature that contains the varying ROW width along it's length. I have street centreline and a polygon layer representing the street ROW area. I've managed a workaround to visualize this by generating perpendicular lines at regular intervals along the centreline features, then clipping the perpendicular lines to the street ROW polygon and symbolizing the length attribute.

What I haven't figured out is how to apply this length attribute to the centreline feature itself so I can play with that data while maintaining the attributes of the original centreline file (street name, addresses, etc.) Since the ROW width would vary along the length of each segment, can it somehow be stored as a z attribute in the shape field?

Anyone have any ideas or other approaches to achieve the same result?

Comment: I think this needs a picture and a question mark to clarify what it is that you are asking.

Comment: Maybe you can try splitting the original street line feature into regular segments and then create only one perpendicular line for each segment. By then clipping the perpendicular lines to the original lines, you get the width of the ROW for each segment (approximately). Spatial join the perpendicular lines back to the original segmented lines and you should have the ROW width as an attribute.